# Python interpolate weather data for heights not measured at

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I need to get weather data for each height ranging between 0m - 25000m. What is the best way to interpolate the data for the missing heights?

I tried this, and it seemed pretty accurate, but it doesn't seem very clean and depends on lots of modules.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate

df = pd.read_fwf(data, widths=[7] * 11)
df = df.drop([0, 1])
df = df.drop(columns=['DWPT', 'RELH', 'MIXR', 'THTA', 'THTE', 'THTV']) #Not needed data, only: pressure, temperature, windspeed and wind direction are needed.


HGHT = np.array(df['HGHT']) #Height
PRES = np.array(df['PRES']) #Pressure
TEMP = np.array(df['TEMP']) #Temperature
DRCT = np.array(df['DRCT']) #Wind direction
SKNT = np.array(df['SKNT']) #Wind speed

Pressure = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(HGHT, PRES) #I only did pressure for the test. 

>>> Pressure(203) #Insert height as argument.
array(1000.)
```

Is there any cleaner way of doing this?

This below is the cleaned up weather table I am using:

```py
data = '''
PRES   HGHT   TEMP   DWPT   RELH   MIXR   DRCT   SKNT   THTA   THTE   THTV


 1022.0     11   26.6   14.6     48  10.32     95      8  297.9  328.2  299.7
 1014.0     81   23.6   12.6     50   9.11    111      9  295.6  322.1  297.2
 1012.0     98   23.5   12.5     50   9.05    115     10  295.6  322.0  297.2
 1000.0    203   22.6   11.6     50   8.65    120     14  295.8  321.0  297.3
  982.0    361   21.4   10.4     49   8.12    134     16  296.1  319.9  297.5
  979.0    387   21.8    8.8     43   7.31    136     16  296.7  318.3  298.1
  968.0    485   21.3    7.4     41   6.70    145     17  297.2  317.1  298.4
  956.0    593   20.8    5.8     38   6.08    146     16  297.8  315.9  298.9
  925.0    876   18.4    5.4     42   6.11    150     14  298.1  316.4  299.2
  850.0   1593   11.8    3.8     58   5.95    145     14  298.5  316.3  299.6
  832.0   1772   10.1    3.6     64   6.01    140     14  298.5  316.5  299.6
  827.0   1822    9.6    3.6     66   6.03    141     13  298.5  316.6  299.6
  814.0   1953    8.8   -0.2     53   4.65    145     12  299.0  313.2  299.9
  802.0   2076    9.8  -13.2     18   1.73    148     12  301.4  307.0  301.7
  775.0   2359    8.7  -18.5     13   1.15    155     10  303.1  306.9  303.3
  751.0   2619    7.6  -23.4      9   0.78    178     10  304.7  307.4  304.8
  728.0   2873    6.1  -19.6     14   1.12    200     10  305.8  309.5  306.0
  718.0   2986    5.4  -17.9     17   1.31    190     10  306.2  310.6  306.5
  700.0   3194    4.2  -14.8     24   1.74    180      8  307.1  312.9  307.4
  657.0   3704    1.6  -16.9     24   1.55    210     12  309.8  315.0  310.1
  616.0   4223   -1.1  -19.1     24   1.38    197     10  312.4  317.2  312.7
  594.0   4510   -3.5  -17.5     33   1.64    190     10  312.9  318.5  313.2
  573.0   4795   -5.9  -15.9     45   1.94    203     10  313.3  319.9  313.7
  561.0   4960   -7.3  -18.9     39   1.54    210     10  313.6  318.8  313.8
  558.0   5002   -7.7  -19.7     38   1.45    209     10  313.6  318.6  313.9
  551.0   5100   -7.3  -35.3      9   0.35    207     10  315.2  316.5  315.3
  550.0   5114   -7.3  -34.3     10   0.38    207     10  315.4  316.8  315.4
  529.0   5416   -8.6  -37.5      8   0.29    200     10  317.3  318.4  317.4
  528.0   5431   -8.7  -37.7      8   0.28    200     10  317.4  318.5  317.4
  500.0   5850  -12.1  -36.1     12   0.35    210     12  318.2  319.6  318.3
  489.0   6019  -13.3  -37.3     11   0.32    215     12  318.8  320.0  318.8
  479.0   6175  -14.4  -38.4     11   0.29    205     10  319.3  320.4  319.4
  456.0   6548  -17.1  -41.1     11   0.23    240     10  320.5  321.4  320.5
  449.0   6665  -17.9  -41.9     10   0.22    245      8  320.9  321.7  320.9
  443.0   6766  -17.9  -30.9     31   0.66    249      7  322.1  324.6  322.2
  427.0   7038  -20.6  -31.0     39   0.68    260      4  322.1  324.6  322.2
  400.0   7520  -25.3  -31.3     57   0.70    260      6  322.0  324.6  322.2
  391.0   7685  -26.9  -31.9     63   0.68    272      7  322.0  324.5  322.2
  390.0   7703  -27.1  -32.1     62   0.67    273      7  322.0  324.5  322.1
  384.0   7815  -27.3  -42.3     23   0.24    281      8  323.2  324.1  323.2
  366.0   8158  -29.3  -47.3     16   0.15    305     10  325.0  325.6  325.1
  355.0   8376  -30.5  -50.5     12   0.11    311      9  326.2  326.6  326.2
  300.0   9550  -39.1  -51.1     27   0.12    345      8  330.1  330.6  330.2
  262.0  10456  -47.0  -56.8     32   0.07    325     10  331.6  331.9  331.6
  250.0  10770  -49.7  -58.7     34   0.06    335     10  332.1  332.3  332.1
  238.0  11089  -52.3  -63.3     25   0.03    328      9  332.8  333.0  332.8
  220.0  11592  -56.5  -62.5     47   0.04    318      7  333.9  334.1  333.9
  208.0  11944  -59.1  -65.1     46   0.03    310      6  335.3  335.4  335.3
  200.0  12190  -60.9  -66.9     45   0.02    290     10  336.2  336.3  336.2
  197.0  12283  -61.5  -67.3     46   0.02    285     12  336.6  336.7  336.6
  188.0  12570  -63.5  -68.4     51   0.02    295     16  338.0  338.1  338.0
  181.0  12805  -61.0  -72.4     21   0.01    290     19  345.6  345.7  345.6
  176.0  12978  -59.2  -75.3     11   0.01    300     10  351.4  351.4  351.4
  174.0  13048  -58.5  -76.5      8   0.01    273      6  353.8  353.8  353.8
  173.0  13085  -58.4  -76.7      8   0.01    260      4  354.5  354.5  354.5
  169.0  13231  -58.2  -77.6      7   0.01    240     10  357.3  357.3  357.3
  162.0  13497  -57.7  -79.2      5   0.00    260     19  362.4  362.4  362.4
  159.0  13614  -57.5  -79.9      4   0.00    270     17  364.7  364.7  364.7
  156.0  13734  -57.3  -80.7      4   0.00    250     10  367.1  367.1  367.1
  151.0  13938  -56.9  -81.9      3   0.00    254     11  371.1  371.2  371.1
  150.0  13980  -56.9  -81.9      3   0.00    255     12  371.8  371.9  371.8
  142.0  14329  -56.7  -82.3      3   0.00    240     16  378.0  378.0  378.0
  135.0  14650  -56.6  -82.6      2   0.00    280     21  383.8  383.8  383.8
  132.0  14793  -56.5  -82.8      2   0.00    280     16  386.4  386.4  386.4
  129.0  14940  -56.5  -82.9      2   0.00    245     16  389.0  389.0  389.0
  127.0  15039  -56.4  -83.0      2   0.00    245     21  390.8  390.9  390.8
  122.0  15295  -56.3  -83.3      2   0.00    275     27  395.6  395.6  395.6
  119.0  15453  -56.2  -83.5      2   0.00    295     21  398.5  398.6  398.5
  117.0  15561  -56.2  -83.6      2   0.00    295     14  400.6  400.6  400.6
  115.0  15671  -56.1  -83.7      2   0.00    255      8  402.6  402.6  402.6
  114.0  15726  -56.1  -83.8      2   0.00    240     10  403.7  403.7  403.7
  109.0  16012  -56.0  -84.1      2   0.00    240     12  409.1  409.2  409.1
  107.0  16129  -55.9  -84.2      2   0.00    200     10  411.4  411.4  411.4
  100.0  16560  -55.7  -84.7      2   0.00    230     17  419.8  419.9  419.8
   98.0  16689  -55.6  -84.7      2   0.00    250     16  422.4  422.4  422.4
   95.0  16888  -55.5  -84.7      2   0.00    235     19  426.4  426.4  426.4
   92.0  17093  -55.4  -84.7      1   0.00    250     23  430.5  430.5  430.5
   87.0  17450  -55.2  -84.6      1   0.00    270     14  437.8  437.8  437.8
   85.0  17599  -55.1  -84.6      1   0.00    245      6  440.9  440.9  440.9
   82.0  17829  -55.0  -84.6      1   0.00    250     10  445.7  445.7  445.7
   78.0  18148  -54.9  -84.6      1   0.00    210     10  452.4  452.5  452.4
   75.0  18399  -54.7  -84.5      1   0.00    240     17  457.8  457.9  457.8
   74.0  18485  -54.7  -84.5      1   0.00    265     12  459.7  459.7  459.7
   70.0  18840  -54.5  -84.5      1   0.00    255     10  467.4  467.5  467.4
   69.0  18932  -54.0  -84.3      1   0.00    265     10  470.4  470.4  470.4
   66.0  19217  -52.5  -83.5      1   0.01      0      0  479.6  479.6  479.6
   65.9  19227  -52.5  -83.5      1   0.01    358      0  479.9  480.0  479.9
   59.0  19937  -53.1  -83.7      1   0.01    185     10  493.9  493.9  493.9
   57.0  20159  -53.3  -83.8      1   0.01    205     17  498.3  498.4  498.3
   55.0  20388  -53.5  -83.9      1   0.01    240     12  503.0  503.0  503.0
   52.0  20748  -53.9  -84.0      1   0.01    200      4  510.3  510.4  510.3
   51.0  20873  -54.0  -84.1      1   0.01    200     10  512.9  513.0  512.9
   50.0  21000  -54.1  -84.1      1   0.01    215     12  515.5  515.6  515.5
   42.6  22025  -53.9  -84.9      1   0.01    100     10  540.2  540.2  540.2
   40.0  22430  -52.1  -83.8      1   0.01     55     10  554.4  554.5  554.4
   39.0  22593  -51.4  -83.4      1   0.01    105     12  560.2  560.3  560.2
   38.8  22626  -51.3  -83.3      1   0.01    109     12  561.4  561.5  561.4
   38.0  22761  -51.4  -83.3      1   0.01    125     14  564.6  564.7  564.6
   37.0  22934  -51.4  -83.4      1   0.01    155     12  568.8  568.9  568.8
   36.0  23111  -51.5  -83.5      1   0.01    165     10  573.1  573.2  573.1
   33.0  23674  -51.7  -83.7      1   0.01    120     10  587.0  587.0  587.0
   32.0  23873  -51.8  -83.8      1   0.01    120     10  591.9  592.0  592.0
   30.0  24290  -51.9  -83.9      1   0.01      5      2  602.5  602.7  602.5
   28.0  24737  -52.0  -83.8      1   0.01     45     10  614.3  614.4  614.3
   27.0  24973  -52.0  -83.7      1   0.01     85     12  620.6  620.7  620.6
   26.0  25217  -52.1  -83.6      1   0.01    100     14  627.1  627.3  627.2
   23.0  26012  -52.2  -83.4      1   0.02    115     10  649.0  649.2  649.0
   22.2  26241  -52.3  -83.3      1   0.02     99      7  655.5  655.7  655.5
   21.0  26603  -51.1  -83.2      1   0.02     75      4  669.5  669.7  669.5
   20.0  26920  -50.1  -83.1      1   0.02     75      6  682.1  682.3  682.1
   19.0  27262  -49.4  -82.8      1   0.02     95     10  694.3  694.6  694.3
   18.0  27622  -48.6  -82.4      1   0.03    125     10  707.5  707.8  707.5
   17.0  28003  -47.9  -82.0      1   0.03     60     10  721.7  722.0  721.7
   16.0  28407  -47.0  -81.6      1   0.03    100     14  737.0  737.4  737.0
   13.0  29791  -44.1  -80.2      1   0.05     65     10  792.0  792.6  792.0
   12.0  30325  -43.0  -79.7      1   0.06    115     14  814.3  815.0  814.3
   11.0  30905  -41.8  -79.1      1   0.07    110      2  839.1  840.0  839.2
   10.0  31540  -40.5  -78.5      1   0.08     80      8  867.2  868.3  867.3
    9.0  32262  -39.1  -78.1      1   0.10     70     10  899.1  900.4  899.2
    8.1  32984  -37.7  -77.7      1   0.12    151     11  932.1  933.8  932.2
    8.0                                       160     12                     

'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this & see if this works for you

```
ind= np.linspace(0,500,500).astype(int)
df.set_index(['HGHT'], inplace=True)
df1=df.reindex(ind)
df1.interpolate(method= 'linear',limit_direction ='both', inplace=True)
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

**Details**

```
ind= np.linspace(0,500,500).astype(int)
```

We generate an array of numbers. In this case i have genrated 0 to 500 and totals numbers to be generated is 500, so each step is one. For your dataset, you will have to do ti till 25000. so, `np.linspace(0,25000,25000)`

```
df.set_index(['HGHT'], inplace=True)
```

We set the index of df as the column to which the generated array has to confirm to.

```
df1=df.reindex(ind)
```

We reindex the df & the output is a new dataframe, you can set it a the same dataframe also.

```
df1.interpolate(method= 'linear',limit_direction ='both', inplace=True)
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

We interlopate the rest of the values using `dataframe.interpolate()` & finally reset the index to have the dataframe like you had before.

Comment: I tried it, but it just changed the entire column to 'None'.

Comment: Can you please paste your original data (where values are missing)?

Comment: This is the original data, I only removed some unnecessary text that could break the pandas `read_fwf ` function. I need to interpolate between the not measured values. Not for the missing ones, since there are non missing.

Comment: ok. now it is much clear. I have updated the solution. see if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want linear interpolation, you can use `np.interp`